# Rock Band Drum Versions

Tags: rock-band-3, rock-band-2

I recently purchased Rock Band 3 and would like to upgrade my old Rock Band 1 drums.  Is there any difference between the base drum kit for RB2 and RB3?

I know RB3 has a new cymbal kit but I cannot find any information on whether inprovements have been made to the core.  It would be cheaper for me to buy used RB2 drums and the RB3 cymbals so I want to know how viable this route is.

Will they work on full pro mode in RB3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the base drum kit for RB2 and RB3?

Not really -- the RB2 drums and the RB3 drums are very, very similar. Having owned both I did not see any important differences between the two.

Both RB2 and RB3 drums support the pro cymbal add on, but be advised the RB3 cymbals are substantially better than the RB2 cymbals.

http://www.fakeplasticrock.com/2010/09/rock-band-3-drums-with-pro-cymbals/

The Rock Band 1 drums are *definitely* to be avoided, however!

Comment: My rock band 1 drum set actually broke at some point. The pedal was really fragile (which is the reason in rock band 2 it got reinforced with a peace of metal), definitely not strong enough for expert gameplay and yes, stay away from those!

Comment: Wow, I never would have expected you would play Rock Band, Jeff!

Comment: Same thing crossed my mind actually, such a busy man in charge of coding horror...

Comment: Guys, I think you are seriously underestimating the amount of stress relief that wailing away on a plastic drum set can provide.  It's essential for busy people; we need to hit things!

Comment: True. I managed to break the red pad on my RB1 kit :(

Answer (score 3):

I would **STRONGLY** recommend buying an [Ion drum set](http://ionaudio.com/ied07). I don't know about RB2 or RB3 drum sets, but the experience I've had with other (RB1, GH: World Tour, GH5) is that they break, they don't last long, and they have a really hard time registering hits. I've had my ion drum set for almost 2 years now, and never had a problem with it. Also, it's compatible with all Guitar Heros and all Rock Bands, so that's a big plus. Although in Guitar Heros you only get 4 drums instead of 5.

Anyway, as I said, I would STRONGLY recommend the Ion drum set =).

Ah and it will work in pro mode for RB3 too.

Comment: Christ, $250.  I bought two Rock Band drumsets from ebay for $40 each, and have never had problems with either..

Comment: Lucky you. Me and a couple friends have had problems with all of them until we bought the ion drumset. Do you play on expert?

Comment: Yes, Pro mode too with the new cymbals.. Though the Mad Katz cymbals do make some songs literally impossible on expert.  Does the Ion come with all three cymbals?  The picture shows only two.

Comment: Yes it does, I got mine and it has the hi-hat, the crash and the ride, it's a really nice investment if you're gonna put a lot of hours into rock band